# Form submitted without include its fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In my current spring project, I have a view with this html form:

```
<form role="form" class="form" id="form" method="post" action="/loja/idiomas/set" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" id="left" multiple="multiple" size="20">...</select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn_left">&lt;&lt;</button>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn_right">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" id="right" name="listaDeIdiomas" multiple="multiple" size="20"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

which it's submitted by this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({height: 360, minHeight: null, maxHeight: null});

  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $( 'form.form' ), url = $form.attr( "action" );
    var posting = $.post( url, $form.serialize() );
    posting.done(function(data){
      if(data == "") {
        $("#alerta_sucesso").css("display", "block");
      } else {
        $("#alerta_erro").find("#texto").text(data);
        $("#alerta_erro").css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Initially, the select `#left` is filled with data, which the user can send to the select `#right`. I checked, this is really working (and the option it's been placed in the select `#right` correctly).

But when I submit the form, no data is sent to the server - I check via browser's developer tools, and no params are being forwarded.

Anyone can  se what's wrong here? The jquery code works with another forms, except this one.

Comment: I do not see any button with id "submit". You refer $('#submit') in JQuery code, where is element with ID submit ?

Comment: Where is your submit button?

Comment: @AnkitVadi @SagarV the button is placed outsite the form tag and it's referenced with the ID `#submit` (it's outside because the form tag is a custom tag created by me using thymeleaf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the items from the second select only be sent to server if they were selected. I manage to select them automatically with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btn_left').click(function() {
  return !$('#left option:selected').remove().appendTo('#right');
 });
 $('#btn_right').click(function() {
  return !$('#right option:selected').remove().appendTo('#left');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the click function for an element with ID "submit". Try using something like

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

where the "target" is the id for your button

Comment: the id `#submit` it's for the button which trigger the action (it's placed outside the form tag because this tag is a custom tag I created with thymeleaf).